# Jenkins inside of Docker need to run DotNet

Tags: docker, jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-plugins

I'm getting a little lost and I need some help.

I'm running Jenkins inside a docker container, and it is running fine.

I am now trying to run 'dotnet build' inside a pipeline, but it says dotnet to not found.

Please can someone help me to get dotnet builds to run inside my Jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - you need to create a DotNet core agent in Docker and assign your pipeline node to that Agent

I found this example

https://github.com/FeynmanFan/JenkinsDocker